# Typescript: Assert unknown input has type Pick<ConcreteType, subset of keys of ConcreteType> for specified keys

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-assertion

When trying to create a generic function to test if an unknown input is a subset of a known object type I run into trouble with Typescript. I want to specify which keys should be present and assert that the input is of type Pick<ConcreteType, subset of keys of ConcreteType>. My assertion

Simplified code:

```
type Rectangle = {
  width: number,
  height: number
}

const assertObject: (o: unknown) => asserts o is Record<PropertyKey, unknown> = (
  o,
) => {
  if (typeof o !== `object`) {
    throw new Error();
  }
};

function assertRectangle <K extends keyof Rectangle>(o: unknown, ...keys: K[]): asserts o is Pick<Rectangle, K>  {
  assertObject(o);
  // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  if (keys.includes(`width` as K) && !o.hasOwnProperty('width')) {
    throw new Error('');
  }
  if (keys.includes(`height` as K) && !o.hasOwnProperty('height')) {
    throw new Error('');
  }
}

const rect = {width: 1, height: 1};
assertRectangle(rect, 'width'); // Pick<Rectangle, "width">
assertRectangle(rect, 'height', 'width'); // Pick<Rectangle, "height" | "width">
```

This code works but not if we remove the `as K` inside `keys.includes`.

```
if (keys.includes(`width`) && !o.hasOwnProperty('width')) {
   throw new Error('');
}
// OR:
if (keys.includes(`width` as const) && !o.hasOwnProperty('width')) {
   throw new Error('');
}
```

> Argument of type '"width"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K'.
> '"width"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'keyof Rectangle'.ts(2345)

I was wondering why `as const` doesn't work here, the problem I am wondering about is that when I or a colleague decide to change or rename properties on the type Rectangle, I would like typescript to warn me when this assert does not longer cover the type. Adding, renaming or subtracting a property on the type will not get catched by this assert.

Comment: This happens because `K` can also be instantiated as `"height"` and `"width"` is not assignable to it.

Comment: Side note: `assertObject` should probably do a `null` check, since `typeof null` is `"object"`.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I don't see why `width` and `height` need to be called out explicitly in `assertRectangle` at all, can you expand on that? You've limited the keys such that they have to be keys of `Rectangle`, so you can just loop through them [like this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zvyN). That also means you don't have the problem that `"width"` is not assignable to `K` (because as @NeriyaCohen said, `K` can be `"height"`). It still catches anywhere someone tries to use a key with `assertRectangle` that isn't a key of `Rectangle` (thanks to the generic constraint).

Comment: @NeriyaCohen, that makes so much sense, thanks, now I understand the problem

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, +1 for the null check. I am doing it in this way because each property/key could have seperate checks. For example the Rectangle can have an id field and I would also want to assert if that id is of type string and matches a uuid regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you've said:

> I am doing it in this way because each property/key could have seperate checks. For example the Rectangle can have an id field and I would also want to assert if that id is of type string and matches a uuid regex

In that case, I'd approach it like this:

1. Loop through `keys` checking that they exist
2. For properties that need additional checks, use `if`/`else if` to identify them and apply the extra checks. (I was surprised to find that `switch` doesn't complain about cases that can never be reached, but `if` does.)

Something like the following — note that in this example I have a check for a property that doesn't exist on `Rectangle`, and TypeScript warns me about that. This is to demonstrate your *"I am wondering about is that when I or a colleague decide to change or rename properties on the type Rectangle"* situation (in this case, let's say `Rectangle` used to have `id` but doesn't anymore).

```typescript
type Rectangle = {
    width: number,
    height: number;
};

const assertObject: (o: unknown) => asserts o is Record<PropertyKey, unknown> = (
    o,
) => {
    if (o === null || typeof o !== `object`) {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− added
        throw new Error();
    }
};

function assertRectangle<K extends keyof Rectangle>(
    o: unknown,
    ...keys: K[]
): asserts o is Pick<Rectangle, K> {
    assertObject(o);
    for (const key of keys) {
        // Basic check
        if (!o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            throw new Error("");
        }
        // Additional per-property checks
        // (I was surprised that `switch` didn't work here to call out property
        // names that aren't on Rectangle like "id" below.)
        if (key === "width" || key === "height") {
            if (typeof o[key] !== "number") {
                throw new Error(`typeof of '${key}' expected to be 'number'`);
            }
        } else if (key === "id") {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−− causes error because `id` isn't a valid
//                                      Rectangle property (e.g., if you remove
//                                      a property from `Rectangle`, TypeScript
//                                      warns you)
            const id = o[key];
            if (typeof id !== "string" || !id) {
                throw new Error(`'${key}' expected to be non-empty string`);
            }
        }
    }
}

declare let rect1: unknown;
declare let rect2: unknown;
declare let rect3: unknown;
assertRectangle(rect1, "width");
rect1; // <== type is Pick<Rectangle, "width">
assertRectangle(rect2, "height", "width");
rect2; // <== type is Pick<Rectangle, "height" | "width">
assertRectangle(rect3, "height", "width", "not-rectangle-property");
// Error −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-n+RS1gAJHg2JSLWvx-JAiAFh2O7QLWYGcLWvRXF62xSL8GCaD4x73ueW7yoqIxcdxXFTHxozLOqSCMJonicGcpFdiJ0DtJQla+POahQAAbqGlAEJxPFadpOk8UuMJQAOMYgCYEDomg6IJDqIC9lAbbMPIykQBpQy6W57lcUghnRuaUAFOEzBQO0+lYO0CQACrgBAADK8AcGQYDAC5HkpW5GYcMoUA2Ywh4fuKKg+BQTheABcSEjRn7HqhRSUMB54qPF6A3nULSUDa0HUHsjoIc65ztJh2FxLh+GEYCRUkewDCKOGEDMIlJkNWQ6DUds1x0cQNw3AQGzwBgs4rhAqhtogACM5jIikkg7XtbZQFgR2GAATOdyR2FdCA3QdD2IAAzC9KIoJI3JvFCy7GMdwAnQkF6UDQHqSBDJ3iFAipBGUP4+J4dIMkyoMwtDl5w84BDA8AIUQODT3Q8+gjAK6BOw9egoQ49yOo+jUWY7S9KMuT1P8LTN4boT17E6T5OU79-MvnTDNXvTG42MA4YQyyECRj5Q7w8liEilAKwG4bcyjEAA)

Comment: Great solution thanks. It is true that the switch statement doesn't protect you against non existing properties. However, the if/else approach doesn't protect you against non implemented properties. Having an id property on the type but not having a case that handles it in the assert function will not be caught (e.g. `default: { throw new Error(\`Unreachable case: ${key}\`); }`). So I think it is saver to use the switch statement here

Comment: @TerryvanWalen - If you want a validation branch for **every** property, then add an `else` at the end with that. `switch` in JavaScript -- unlike some other similar languages -- is effectively just `if`/`else if`/`else` (which is why I'm surprised TypeScript doesn't complain about `case "id"` when `key` can't have the value `"id"`). But yes, you can use `switch`, you just lose the proactive notification of obsolete validation code.

Comment: (That said, if the `case` labels are literals, the JavaScript engine could optimize a `switch` to a jump table as with some other languages [I don't know if engines *do*, but they *could*]. It's really only when the case labels are expressions (!!) that it matters that it's different to other languages.)